# How to read express cookie in socket.io authorization process?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, socket.io

Many articles ([here's one](https://github.com/vortec/lolbr/blob/master/lib/lolbr.js)) shows how to utilize the `authorization` event to extract the cookie of the express session:

```
io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
            if (!data.headers.cookie) {
                return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
            }
            else {
                // extract the signed cookie..
            }
```

I printed `data.headers` and there's no `cookie` property.

I've inspected the cookies (via Chrome developer tools) and `connect.sid` domain is `localhost` whereas `io` domain is `127.0.0.1`. Maybe the problem is there but I'm not sure how to change it.

Another aspect is, the express cookie is used by server A (with port 3000) and the socket.io cookie is used by server B (with port 4000).

I'd be glad for a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it actually. The problem was indeed with the domain. You should change the `socket.io` domain to `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Hope it will help someone!

Comment: I know this is old - but I've been struggling with a similar issue for days now, and switching the ip to the domain fixed it for me as well. Thank you so much!